# Why isn't my 'for loop' working when I try to scrape these download links?

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

So I am trying to run this chunk of code as a loop.

```
  url <- links$link[1]
target_page <- read_html(url)
x <- GET(url, add_headers('user-agent' = 'Gov employment data scraper (smtorres@ucla.edu)'))
target_page <- x %>% read_html(url)
target_page
remote_driver$navigate(url)
remote_driver$getTitle()

html_source <- remote_driver$getPageSource()
target_page <- read_html(html_source[[1]])

target_page
load = html_nodes(target_page, xpath='/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div/p/a')
paste0("https://www.congress.gov", load %>% html_attr("href"))
```

I include this because this individual one works perfectly and does so for an entry in lists$link.
What is confusing to me is that when I run this as a for loop:

```
links$download = 1:26
for(y in links$link) {
  url <- y
target_page <- read_html(url)
x <- GET(url, add_headers('user-agent' = 'Gov employment data scraper (smtorres@ucla.edu)'))
target_page <- x %>% read_html(url)
target_page
remote_driver$navigate(url)
remote_driver$getTitle()

html_source <- remote_driver$getPageSource()
target_page <- read_html(html_source[[1]])

target_page
load = html_nodes(target_page, xpath='/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div/p/a')
links$download <- paste0("https://www.congress.gov", load %>% html_attr("href"))

}
```

It returns as "https://www.congress.gov" for every cell.
Any ideas?

re: here is the code to create link

```
   library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(RSelenium)
library(tidyverse)
library(httr2)

url \<- "https://www.congress.gov/congressional-record/50th-congress/browse-by-date"
target_page \<- read_html(url)

x <- GET(url, add_headers('user-agent' = 'Gov employment data scraper (smtorres@ucla.edu)'))
target_page <- x %>% read_html(url)
target_page

driver <- rsDriver(browser = "firefox",
               chromever = NULL)
remote_driver <- driver[["client"]]
remote_driver$open()
remote_driver$navigate(url)
remote_driver$getTitle()

html_source <- remote_driver$getPageSource()
target_page <- read_html(html_source[[1]])

target_page

tab = html_nodes(target_page, xpath='//*[@id="innerbox_20-3"]')
daylinks <- tab %>% html_nodes("a")
link <- paste0("https://www.congress.gov",daylinks %>% html_attr("href")

links <- data.frame(link)
```

Comment: Why not just do `for url in links`? instead of immediately renaming it?

Comment: I can't replicate your problem because I don't have `link`

Comment: @AzorAhai-him- I just added that code for you!

Answer (score 0):

After great effort I realized it was an indexing error here is the fix for anyone wondering about this problem.....

```
    links$download = 1:26
    for(y in links$download) {
      url <- links$link[y]
    target_page <- read_html(url)
    x <- GET(url, add_headers('user-agent' = 'Gov employment data scraper (smtorres@ucla.edu)'))
    target_page <- x %>% read_html(url)
    target_page
    remote_driver$navigate(url)
    remote_driver$getTitle()
    
    html_source <- remote_driver$getPageSource()
    target_page <- read_html(html_source[[1]])
    
    target_page
    load = html_nodes(target_page, xpath='/html/body/div[2]/div/main/div[2]/div/p/a')
    
    links$download[y] = paste0("https://www.congress.gov", load %>% html_attr("href"))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).